# List view in Blackberry10 cascades

Tags: blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

how to add on-click event in list view ,if i click the list view means i want to go next qml layout,how to do this.?i have tried on Triggered but it's not working

Comment: have yo chek the log using slog2info ?

Comment: No,can u send some reference

Comment: here how to debug in momentics https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/documentation/getting_started/tools/debugging.html